# ¿Por qué siempre se genera la excepción de FormatException?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Lo que yo quiero hacer en este programa es que al ingresar los números en su correspondiente `textbox`.

Y después al hacer clic en el `button` se genere la respuesta en el `label 4` que está debajo del `button`, ahora quiero hacer esa operación desde una clase derivada de Form1 que es la del diseño y crear un objeto donde sale la operación en la clase suma, me podrían corregir o lo que hay que hacer
Postdata: Las instrucciones que están en el método sum si funcionan al ponerlos a la función `void calcularRespuesta`, ¿por qué?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Alex, debes mejorar un poco la pregunta. No es necesario las capturas de Pantalla del VS, en su lugar coloca el código y posiblemente una captura de la formulario

Comment: Lo siento, no lo sabía, lo que pasa es que estoy desde un teléfono

Comment: La clase `suma.cs` no puede acceder a los componentes `number1` y `number2`.

Comment: Porque si modifique a number1 y number2 como protected ya que la clase suma hereda de Form1

Comment: O que me aconsejas ¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria ideal que la la clase `suma.cs` quede de este modo

```
public class Matematicas //Esto tu le pones el nombre. Luego se instancia como new Nombre();
{
    // esto quiere decir que devolvera una valor entero
    //       |
    //       v
    public int sumar(int n1, int n2)
    {
        //Hace la suma y lo devuelve
        return n1 + n2;
    }
}


//Otra archivo
public void buttonClick()
{
    Matematicas maths = new Matematicas();        

    int n1 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    int n2 = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    mostrarRespuesta.Text = maths.sumar(n1, n2).ToString();
}
```

¿Recomendaciones?, obligaciones:

1: Que la clase `suma.cs` no derive de `Form1`.

2: No modificar los componentes de `Form1.Designer.cs`.

**Editado**

Me falto el ¿Por qué?. Al ser un clase que hereda de `Form1` los valores de `Form1` no existen, son todos nulos.

Ej:

```
//el valor 'Text' en ese momento es nulo.
Convert.ToInt32(number1.Text);
```

Y por eso arroja error porque no se puede convertir el valor nulo del componente.

Espero a verte aclarado las cosas, si no es el caso, solo pregunta.

Comment: Podría agregarse que realicé una validación para saber si number1.Text contiene un caracter numerico y posteriormente realice la conversión Convert.ToInt32(number1.Text);, ya que aquí es donde se produce el error.

Comment: Gracias muchachos, feliz visperas de navidad ya me salió el programa

Answer (score 0):

Este un problema de validacion de datos. Lo mejor es no permitir que el usuario ingrese datos errones

La recomendación es utilizar un `MaskedTextBox` en lugar de un `TextBox`.
con la propiedad MaskedTextBox.ValidatingType

```
maskedTextBox1.ValidatingType = typeof(int);
```

Y utilizar el evento `TypeValidationCompleted` para informar al usuario cuando ingresa datos errones.

[Revisa el siguiente tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/kkx4h3az(v=vs.110).aspx)